# How do I empty out a collection if I'm using TryUpdateModel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, model-binding

I have a model that contains a `List<PhoneNumber>` property. I use TryUpdateModel in my update actions. Adding new numbers and changing existing numbers works fine. Removing existing numbers, however, works only if I don't try to remove everything. If I remove everything from the list, none of the items get deleted.

I realize that this is probably by design, but what's the recommended approach for dealing with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently going with this approach:

```
List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers = new List<PhoneNumber>();
TryUpdateModel<List<PhoneNumber>>(phoneNumbers, "Student.PhoneNumbers", form);

if (phoneNumbers.Count == 0)
{
    student.PhoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is 2 years old and for MVC2. However, I did find the same issue in MVC3 and found the culprit and the solution. I answered the following question since it was the same problem that I was having, and hopefully, the solution is also applicable here without changes.

Related answer: [TryUpdateModel does not empty a collection of items when all items are removed on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14595926/147507).