# TryUpdateModel does not empty a collection of items when all items are removed on screen

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am working with asp.net mvc 3 and having trouble with the use of tryUpdateModel while posting changes.

I have a model that contains multiple lists of items and my view can add or remove items by Ajax and I am able to save changes with a save button.

When I add items to the collections, TryUpdateModel works just fine, but when I remove ALL items in a collection, this collection is not posted in form values anymore and TryUpdateModel does nothing instead of clearing my collection.

how can I handle this scenario ? Has somebody found a workaround to this ? Do I have to override the DefaultModelBinder ?

Thanks

Comment: If the collection items are removed via ajax, why would TryUpdateModel do anything (regarding the collection)? What is left to clear?

Comment: Yes, I am adding/removing items via AJAX using a Partial view that will render the list with the item removed or a new item added. But I am not saving changes at this time, just updating the view with the item removed/added. Then I click on my save button, it posts back everything and then save in my DB the whole object graph.

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't know why it doesn't clear the collection, but a workaround might be to just detect when the relevant form values are missing, and manually removing the items. Something like:

```
public ActionResult Edit(SomeEntity obj)
{
    if(Request.Form["expectedFormValue"] == null)
    {
        obj.YourCollection.Clear();
    }
    TryUpdateModel(obj);
}
```

Comment: In my case, I have many lists in an object graph, if I can avoid having to test if each collection is not empty it will be great.
If I have no other solutions, I'll go for your trick.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've been just dealing with this problem. As it turns out, [the code for `TryUpdateModel`](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/ASP.NET-Mvc-3/blob/master/mvc3/src/SystemWebMvc/Mvc/Controller.cs#L461) has nothing wrong with it, but it completely depends on what the `ValueProvider` gives.

As for AJAX (my case as well), it's really probable that the `JsonValueProviderFactory` is the one parsing the response and giving values to the Controller that executes the `TryUpdateModel` method, who will never find out those values where there. Since `TryUpdateModel` only updates the destination model based on the properties provided by the value provider, it won't touch the emptied collections because those properties are not sent by the provider at all.

The code that makes this happen is [this line in `JsonValueProviderFactory`](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/ASP.NET-Mvc-3/blob/master/mvc3/src/SystemWebMvc/Mvc/JsonValueProviderFactory.cs#L22), where a zero-sized array will never get a value added to the backing store, thus making the property "dissapear".

I found a report for this bug in the ASP.NET Codeplex Site ([Json Request with empty array](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/9807)) from January 2012, and wallymathieu (the submitter) provided a patch that will take care of that. This is the relevant part of the patch:

```
//BEGIN CHANGE
if (l.Count == 0) {
    AddToBackingStore(backingStore, prefix, null);
}
else for (int i = 0; i < l.Count; i++) {
//END CHANGE
```

What he is doing right there is adding the property with a null value when the array is sent as empty.

You can make your own `ValueProviderFactory` with the code that's exposed right there and hook it up to your application by doing this in your `Global.asax` file, `Application_Start` method:

```
ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Remove(ValueProviderFactories.Factories.OfType<JsonValueProviderFactory>().FirstOrDefault());
ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new YourOwnJsonValueProviderFactory());
```

This did solve my problem, I hope it does it for your too and future *TryUpdateModel'ers*.